# change the superclass of object in Python

Tags: python, reflection

I was reading about reflection in Python and came across this statement:

> Structural Reflection. It is possible to modify the set of methods a class offers and the set of field an object has. We can also modify the class an object is instance of, and the set of super-classes a class inherits from.

which is stated on this [here](http://www.reflection.uniovi.es/nrrs/description.shtml).

I tried to implement an example where I can modify the class of an instance in Python:

```
class Child():
    nmbrMovies = 0
    nmbrBooks  = 3

class Adult():
    nmbrMovies = 2
    nmbrBooks  = 5

class Member(Child):
    pass
```

where I want to have an instance of the Member class say, `x`which initially inherits from the Child class, thus inheriting the maximum amounts of movies and books that can be rent in a fictional library. When the person/member is becomes an `Adult`, I would like to simply change the superclass of the member to `Adult`. I know this is not the trivial way to implement such a structure, but I wanted an example to test this functionality of Python.

Does anybody know if what I am trying to do is possible? Or did I misunderstand that property of Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Child():
    nmbrMovies = 0
    nmbrBooks  = 3

class Adult():
    nmbrMovies = 2
    nmbrBooks  = 5

class Member(Child):
    pass

x = Member()
```

`Member` starts out inheriting from `Child`:

```
print(Member.__bases__)
# (<class __main__.Child at 0xb74a141c>,)
```

It is possible to change this to `Adult`:

```
Member.__bases__ = (Adult,)
print(Member.__bases__)
# (<class __main__.Adult at 0xb74a144c>,)
```

Now `x.nmbrMovies` finds `Adult.nmbrMovies`:

```
print(x.nmbrMovies)
# 2
```

It is also possible to change the instance's class. `x` starts out as an instance of `Member`:

```
print(x.__class__)
# __main__.Member
```

but we can change it to say, `Child`:

```
x.__class__ = Child
print(x.nmbrMovies)
# 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. Especially the comparison between the change of the superclass of a class and an instance of a class was very helpful.